# Spring Boot not loading the active application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to activate profiles based on the environment as documented [here](http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-properties-per-maven-profile/)

For the most part it works. However, I've hit an odd scenario.
I have three `application-{profile}.properties` files as follows :

`application-dev.properties`

`application-uat.properties`

`application-release.properties`

When I deploy a war file to uat, Spring is picking up a JDBC connection from the release file. The application.properties file contains one line -

spring.profiles.active=uat

If I change the name of the application-release.properties file to application-release.properties.tmp then Spring picks up the connection from application-uat.properties.
Any ideas.
BTW I'm using Spring.Boot 2.2.0-RELEASE

Comment: what if you explicitly run you app with -Dspring.profiles.active=uat parameter?

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion but the application is an enterprise MVC application deployed to Apache/Tomcat as a war file. The route I am using is a documented Spring route and I would far prefer to use it and would therefore be interested if anyone else has observed this issue and found a workaround..

Comment: How are you loading the `application-release.properties`, as it feels like you are bypassing the Spring Boot mechanisms here. I would suggest specifiying the `spring.profiles.active` externally and in this case that means registering it in JNDI in Tomcat for that application (Spring will detect it from JNDI as well).

Comment: are all the property files in `src/main/resources` of the applicataion and there by in the same folder in the war file? Because sometimes the location of the property file will override. There is some priority order for where the property files are located - like inside  the war, on the file system outside the war and so on

Comment: Many thanks all.
In answer to M.Deinum - Spring Boot is loading properties from my application-uat.properties file but only when the application-release.properties file is deleted or removed. This suggests that Spring is not being bypassed. Also there is an application-dev.properties file present. When I change the single line in application.properties from spring.profiles.active=uat to spring.profiles.active=dev it works but only if application-release.properties is not present. However, I will try your suggestion but I would like to have the application running as documented by Spring.

Comment: To answer MohamedSanaula. Yes all files are in the same directory (src/main/resources) in both dev and in the war file.

Comment: Just taken a look at JNDI as suggested by M. Deinum.  Sorry I don't think that will work as it seems (stop me if i'm wrong) to deal with the loading of a datasource only.  That would be fine if that was the only property in my application.properties file.  There are many tens of other properties specific to the environment that have to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Not sure which of the two changes that I made solved the issue but here it is.

1. When reading the comments in Daniel Olszewski's article, Marcelo Martins says that it is unnecessary to specify resource filtering in pom.xml when using 'spring-boot-starter-parent' which was further confirmed by Daniel.  As I am using 'spring-boot-starter-parent', I removed it.
   To solve my problem I re-inserted it.

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
```

2. I upgraded the maven plugin to 2.2.0.RELEASE

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Further to my answer above. There might be another issue in the mix. I have just deployed another build and hit the same problem.  However, restarting Tomcat resolved the issue.